# Statically defined KeyDeserializer not found but if defined locally everything perfect

Tags: java, json, static, jackson, sortedmap

I am baffled by how registering a custom `KeyDeserializer` works.

Here is my code:

### Matchday.java

```
package com.example;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Matchday implements Serializable, Comparable<Matchday> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8823049187525703664L;

    private final int matchdayNumber;

    public Matchday(final int matchdayNumber) {
        this.matchdayNumber = matchdayNumber;
    }

    public int getMatchdayNumber() {
        return matchdayNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Matchday o) {
        return Integer.compare(matchdayNumber, o.getMatchdayNumber());
    }

    @Override
    public final int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(matchdayNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof Matchday && Integer.valueOf(matchdayNumber).equals(((Matchday) obj).matchdayNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(matchdayNumber);
    }
}
```

### TeamPlayer.java

```
package com.example;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;

public class TeamPlayer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6057852081020631549L;

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this).append("id", id).append("name", name).append("surname", surname).build()
                .toString();
    }
}
```

Now if I define a custom map key deserializer for my class Matchday.java, it works like a charm if I do it like this.

### KeyDeserializerTest.java

```
package com.example;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.SortedMap;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Version;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.KeyDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

public class KeyDeserializerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final SimpleModule mySimpleModule = new SimpleModule("dummy", new Version(0, 0, 0, "dummy", "dummy", "dummy"));
        mySimpleModule.addKeyDeserializer(Matchday.class, new KeyDeserializer() {

            @Override
            public Object deserializeKey(String arg0, DeserializationContext arg1)
                    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
                return new Matchday(Integer.valueOf(arg0));
            }
        });
        objectMapper.registerModule(mySimpleModule);

        final InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                "{\"1\":[{\"id\": 1, \"name\": \"Arkadiusz\", \"surname\": \"Malarz\"}]}".getBytes());
        SortedMap<Matchday, List<TeamPlayer>> map = objectMapper.readValue(inputStream,
                new TypeReference<SortedMap<Matchday, List<TeamPlayer>>>() {
                });
        System.out.println(map);
    }

}
```

It prints

```
{1=[com.example.TeamPlayer@3a8624[id=1,name=Arkadiusz,surname=Malarz]]}
```

But if I define both the object mapper and my deserializer instances as static attributes then I get the following exception!

### KeyDeserializerStaticTest.java

```
package com.example;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.SortedMap;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Version;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.KeyDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

public class KeyDeserializerStaticTest {
    public static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = createObjectMapper();

    private static final KeyDeserializer MATCHDAY_KEY_DESERIALIZER = new KeyDeserializer() {

        @Override
        public Object deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext ctxt)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            return new Matchday(Integer.valueOf(key));
        }
    };

    private static ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(createSimpleModule());
        return objectMapper;
    }

    private static Module createSimpleModule() {
        SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule("dummy", new Version(0, 0, 0, "dummy", "dummy", "dummy"));
        simpleModule.addKeyDeserializer(Matchday.class, MATCHDAY_KEY_DESERIALIZER);
        return simpleModule;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                "{\"1\":[{\"id\": 1, \"name\": \"Arkadiusz\", \"surname\": \"Malarz\"}]}".getBytes());
        SortedMap<Matchday, List<TeamPlayer>> map = OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(inputStream,
                new TypeReference<SortedMap<Matchday, List<TeamPlayer>>>() {
                });
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class com.example.Matchday]
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@bbc1e0; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportMappingException(DeserializationContext.java:1234)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._handleUnknownKeyDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:585)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findKeyDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:168)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findKeyDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:499)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.createContextual(MapDeserializer.java:247)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleSecondaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:681)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:481)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:3899)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3794)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2915)
    at com.example.KeyDeserializerStaticTest.main(KeyDeserializerStaticTest.java:43)
```

What is wrong here? Semantically there is no difference between the above presented main methods. Is this a feature that is somewhere documented or is it simply a bug in Jackson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root problem here was the order of initialization of static variables.

It is

```
public static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = createObjectMapper();

private static final KeyDeserializer MATCHDAY_KEY_DESERIALIZER = new KeyDeserializer() {

    @Override
    public Object deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return new Matchday(Integer.valueOf(key));
    }
};
```

while it should be

```
private static final KeyDeserializer MATCHDAY_KEY_DESERIALIZER = new KeyDeserializer() {

    @Override
    public Object deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return new Matchday(Integer.valueOf(key));
    }
};

public static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = createObjectMapper();
```

This was hard to spot because the method `addKeyDeserializer(Class<?>, KeyDeserializer)` of the class `SimpleModule` silently adds `null` references to an internal key deserializers' map. In my opinion it should throw a `NullPointerException` upon trying adding a key deserializer reference that is `null`.

The Jackson code for it looks like this.

First `addKeKeyDeserializer(Class<?>, KeyDeserializer)`

```
public SimpleModule addKeyDeserializer(Class<?> type, KeyDeserializer deser)
{
    if (_keyDeserializers == null) {
        _keyDeserializers = new SimpleKeyDeserializers();
    }
    _keyDeserializers.addDeserializer(type, deser);
    return this;
}
```

there is no check here whether `deser` is `null`.

Then it delegates to addDeserializer(Class, KeyDeserializer) of class `SimpleKeyDeserializers`.

```
public SimpleKeyDeserializers addDeserializer(Class<?> forClass, KeyDeserializer deser)
{
    if (_classMappings == null) {
        _classMappings = new HashMap<ClassKey,KeyDeserializer>();
    }
    _classMappings.put(new ClassKey(forClass), deser);
    return this;
}
```

Here is the `null` reference also ignored and silently put into `_classMappings` map.

[Here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1447) is the issue I posted on GitHub together with the discussion.